# How can i get the top result only from dataset?

Tags: sql, mysql

i have data set which contains multiple rows with same id but different statuses like gold, silver and bronze.
but I only required the top status out of it and ignore any other status with the same id.

| id | status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 402 | Gold | 5/3/2019 |
| 402 | Silver | 5/3/2018 |
| 402 | Bronze | 5/1/2018 |
| 405 | Silver | 5/3/2020 |
| 405 | Bronze | 5/3/2019 |
| 408 | Bronze | 5/3/2019 |
| 408 | Gold | 5/3/2020 |

I'll be required 405- Silver, 402- Gold and 408- Gold I'm

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Bohemian it has been updated with the text data set.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to give ability to meaningfully order the statuses, convert to that to find the best by number, then convert back to the name:

```
with positions(position, name) as (
  select 1, 'Gold' union all
  select 2, 'Silver' union all
  select 3, 'Bronze'
),
best_positions as (
  select
    id,
    min(position) best_position
  from medal m
  join positions p on p.name = m.status
  group by id
)
select
  id,
  name
from best_positions b
join positions p on p.position = b.best_position
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZBz4Tn_G).